# Suppress echo notice in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to use `echo $var;` in my code but sometimes it doesn't exist, so I get a notice from PHP. I don't want to disable all notices from PHP. Is it possible to prevent notice for this statement only?

Note: I tried `@echo $var;` but it gives me another error. I also found an alternate `echo (isset($var) ? $var: '');` but it is quite long and I don't want to type it everytime.

Comment: Note: Please read it correct. I don't want to disable notices

Comment: Why not just give these variables default values to begin with?

Comment: I think using isset($var) is the right way to do it. From the [http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php]:
Relying on the default value of an uninitialized variable is problematic in the case of including one file into another which uses the same variable name. It is also a major security risk with register_globals turned on. E_NOTICE level error is issued in case of working with uninitialized variables, however not in the case of appending elements to the uninitialized array. isset() language construct can be used to detect if a variable has been already initialized.

Comment: Why are you trying to echo an empty variable in the first place?

Comment: It is actually a registration form which shows the form with data in case of an error

Comment: `First Name <input type="text" name="first_name" id="first_name" value="<?php echo @$first_name ?>"><br />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use either one of the following

```
echo @$var;
@print $var;
```

Comment: Bingo! It worked. I was trying `@echo $var;` earlier.

Comment: Yes, I believe this is because `echo` is no regular function but a language construct

Comment: Actually, I read about `@include` earlier, so I was trying to apply the same thing here. Anyway, thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is :

```
echo @$var;
```

Having the @ in front of the echo statemtn causes syntaxt error